# Simple form with jquery select field not working properly if form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, error-handling, simple-form, jquery-chosen

I have a multi-select input field for a form in rails.  It works perfectly except for when a user submits a value that the validator in the model will not accept.  When the page re-renders and displays the error message, the form field changes from a multi-select field to a text field.  I think the problem is that rails is for some reason changing the css class.  Here is the controller that loads the instance variables for the form:

```
def edit
    @skills = Skill.all.collect {|skill| skill.label}
    @profile = current_user.profile
end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@profile, :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.input :tag_list, collection: @skills, 
          input_html: {class: 'chosen-select', multiple: true, 
          style: 'width: 390px; height: 40px; border-radius: 5px;'},  
          placeholder: 'Tags (seperated by commas)', label: "-" %> <br />
        <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the update controller:

```
def update

    @profile = current_user.profile

    begin
      if @profile.update_attributes!(profile_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated profile."
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
      else
        render :action => 'edit'
      end
    rescue
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
```

The form works perfectly when it is redered the first time.  The html generated for the field looks like this:

```
<div class="input select optional profile_tag_list">
  <label class="select optional" for="profile_tag_list">-</label>
  <input name="profile[tag_list][]" type="hidden" value="" />
    <select class="select optional chosen-select" id="profile_tag_list" 
      multiple="multiple" name="profile[tag_list][]" 
      placeholder="Tags (seperated by commas)" 
      style="width: 390px; height: 40px; border-radius: 5px;">
         <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
         <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
         <option value="python">python</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But when it renders after the update action fails, the html is like this:

```
<div class="input string optional profile_tag_list field_with_errors">
   <label class="string optional" for="profile_tag_list">-</label>
   <input class="string optional chosen-select" id="profile_tag_list" 
     multiple="multiple"  name="profile[tag_list][]" 
     placeholder="Tags (seperated by commas)" 
     style="width: 390px; height: 40px; border-radius: 5px;" type="text"
     value="PHP" />
       <span class="error">Please only submit skills from the list.</span>
</div>
```

How do I get the form to still display a select field when it re-renders?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each request is stateless you need to rebuild the `@skills` instance variable before going back to the edit form.  Also, you don't typically want to use the "!" in the `update_attributes` call because that will say to throw a RecordInvalid error if any validation error occurs.  You can just use:

```
if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated profile."
  redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)
else
  @skills = Skill.all.collect {|skill| skill.label}
  render :action => 'edit'
end
```

If the instance variable setup becomes complicated, you could move it into a shared method that is used by both the `edit` and `update` methods.  And if you are running into some other kind of error other than RecordInvalid, then you could consider using the begin/rescue structure.